# Google Cloud Storage - Listing objects concurrently (Go)

Tags: go, concurrency, google-cloud-storage, goroutine

I have a large number of objects in a GCS bucket that I want to list as fast as possible. The GCS API [docs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/storage/objects/list_files.go) show this example:

```golang
it := client.Bucket(bucket).Objects(ctx, nil)
for {
    attrs, err := it.Next()
    if err == iterator.Done {
        break
    }
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Bucket(%q).Objects: %v", bucket, err)
    }
    fmt.Fprintln(w, attrs.Name)
}
```

But the [API docs](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/storage#BucketHandle.Objects) say that the iterator returned by `Objects` is not concurrency safe.

The [wiki](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/wiki/Iterator-Guidelines) shows a `iterator.Pager` to control pagination, but no examples for concurrency:

```golang
it := client.Books(ctx, shelfName)
p := iterator.NewPager(it, pageSize, "") 
for {
    var books []*library.Book
    nextPageToken, err := p.NextPage(&books)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for _, b := range books {
        process(b)
    }
    if nextPageToken == "" {
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to do it at a higher level since `ObjectIterator` is not safe for concurrent use. Instead, break up your query into multiple by using `StartOffset` an `EndOffset` in your [Query](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/storage#Query) object. The main downside is that you need some prior knowledge of the distribution of objects by name.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> it := client.Books(ctx, shelfName)
> p := iterator.NewPager(it, pageSize, "") 
> for {
>     var books []*library.Book
>     nextPageToken, err := p.NextPage(&books)
>     if err != nil {
>         return err
>     }
>     for _, b := range books {
>         process(b)
>     }
>     if nextPageToken == "" {
>         break
>     }
> }
> ```

You can add concurrency to this code by running the more time-taking part of your code in separate goroutines. Assuming the `process(book *library.Book)` function runs for a long time, you can do either  of

```
for _, b := range books {
    go process(b)
}
```

or

```
go func(books []*library.Book) {
    for _, b := range books {
        process(b)
    }
}(books)
```

or even a combination of the two depending on how your `process` functions works. Since the iterator is not concurrency safe, try to avoid its sharing, but you are free to do whatever you want with the value extracted from each iteration. You can try applying the same logic with the first code example.